# Align textboxes differently in HTML

Tags: html, css

How can I align a set of textboxes like it's shown on the following image:

[image]

I tried text align for the center,but can't get the side ones at the same time.

Thanks in advance.

Here's what I tried:

```
        <div  class = "txtBoxMid">

        Lorern Ipsum </br>

        <input type="text" name="name">

        </br>
        </br>

        Lorern Ipsum</br>

        <input type="text" name="name" >

        </br>
        </br>

        Lorern Ipsum</br>

        <input type="text" name="name">

        </div>

        <div class = "txtBoxLeft">
        Lorern Ipsum </br>

        <input type="text" name="name">

        </br>
        </br>

        Lorern Ipsum</br>

        <input type="text" name="name" >

        </br>
        </br>

        Lorern Ipsum</br>

        <input type="text" name="name">

        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.txtBoxMid
{

text-align:center;

}

.txtBoxLeft
{
text-align:left;
}
```

Tried a bunch of things. Nothing worked :(

Comment: please show some examples of code you tried, or set up a fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using `label` elements to wrap the `input`s, thereby containing the `input` element and its relevant text, and allowing a click on the text to focus the `input`:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    <label>Label text
        <input />
    </label>
    <!-- other repeated elements removed for brevity -->
</form>
```

With the CSS:

```
/* entirely aesthetic, adjust to taste */
form {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

label {
    display: inline-block; /* allows 'width' to be assigned and applied */
    width: 30%; /* to allow three elements per row */
    text-align: center; 
    margin: 0 1% 1em 1%; /* spacing, aesthetics, adjust to taste */
}

input {
    width: 80%; /* aesthetics, adjust to taste */
    margin: 0.5em auto;
    display: block; /* forces the input element to its own line */
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/cGj6J/).

Comment: I'm glad you liked it! :)

Answer (score 1):

use `float` or `inline-block` to accomplish that.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily accomplish this by putting each form and label in a parent box and style that box with:

```
.aBox {
    width: 33%;
    float: left;
}
```

To center the content, just style the label box and the form box. E.G:

```
.label, .formParent {
    text-align: center;
}
```

That will give you three columns. You then just keep adding boxes. For example:

```
<div class="aBox" id="num1">
    <div class="label">Hello.</div>
    <form class="formParent">
        <input type="text" class="field">
    </form>
</div>
<div class="aBox" id="num2">
    <div class="label">Hello 2.</div>
    <form class="formParent">
        <input type="text" class="field">
    </form>
</div>
<div class="aBox" id="num3">
    <div class="label">Hello 3.</div>
    <form class="formParent">
        <input type="text" class="field">
    </form>
</div>
<div class="aBox" id="num4">
    <div class="label">Hello 4.</div>
    <form class="formParent">
        <input type="text" class="field">
    </form>
</div>
<div class="aBox" id="num5">
    <div class="label">Hello 5.</div>
    <form class="formParent">
        <input type="text" class="field">
    </form>
</div>
<div class="aBox" id="num6">
    <div class="label">Hello 6.</div>
    <form class="formParent">
        <input type="text" class="field">
    </form>
</div>
<div class="aBox" id="num7">
    <div class="label">Hello 7.</div>
    <form class="formParent">
        <input type="text" class="field">
    </form>
</div>
<div class="aBox" id="num8">
    <div class="label">Hello 8.</div>
    <form class="formParent">
        <input type="text" class="field">
    </form>
</div>
<div class="aBox" id="num9">
    <div class="label">Hello 9.</div>
    <form class="formParent">
        <input type="text" class="field">
    </form>
</div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/U69sh/